# Interceptor vs Decorator

Tags: angularjs

What I'm trying to do is reset an idle user timeout every time a backend call is completed. I'm having difficulty figuring out whether I should use a $http interceptor or using $provide.decorator to implement this functionality. Or maybe there is a different route I should go?

Comment: both of them :) are you using httpBackaned ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an interceptor in this instance.  The decorator path would work here also, but it can lead to confusing behavior and hard to find bugs.  The $http interceptor interface gives you a clear-cut way to act on http responses globally in your application.

Additionally if you need request-specific interceptors, have a look at `ngResource`.  The `$resource` provider allows you to define interceptors at the request level, something $http doesn't provide out of the box.